# C++: Creating derived class that has access to private variables of base?

Tags: c++

I have an abstract class `base` with private member variable `base_var`. I want to create a derived class, which also has `base_var` as a private member.

To me, this seems like an obvious thing you would want to do. `base` is abstract so it will never be instantiated. The only time I will create a `base`-object is if it is actually a derived object, so obviously when I give ´base´ a private member variable, what I am really trying to do is give that variable to all of its derived objects.

However, the below diagram seems to suggest that this is not doable with inheritance?

[image]

Why not? What would then even be the point of having private stuff in an abstract class? That class will never be instantiated, so all that private stuff is essentially useless?

Comment: You shouldn't even try. If you really have to access it from a subclass, make it `protected`.

Comment: _"...so all that private stuff is essentially useless..."_ you can have an abstract class with some concrete methods that use private data.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that. When it's private, it's private for a reason. You shouldn't mess with other classes' business and violate their encapsulation. This is like one of the most solid OO design principles.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the below diagram seems to suggest that this is not doable with inheritance?

Correct, `private` members of a class can not be accessed by derived classes.  If You want a member of a class to be accessible by its derived classes but not by the outside, then You have to make it `protected`.

> Why not? What would then even be the point of having private stuff in an abstract class? That class will never be instantiated, so all that private stuff is essentially useless?

Even an abstract class can have member functions which act on a (`private`) member variable.  Consider (somewhat silly example, but well):

```
class MaxCached
{
  private:
  int cache = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

  public:
  bool put(int value)
  {
    if (value > cache)
    {
      cache = value;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  int get() const
  {
    return cache;
  }

  virtual void someInterface() const = 0;
};
```

Deriving from this class gives You the functionality of the base class (`put` and `get`) without the danger of breaking it (by for example writing a wrong value to `cache`).

*Side note: Above is a purely made up example! You shouldn't add such a cache (which is independent of Your interface) into the abstract base class.  As it stands the example breaks with the "Single Responsibility Principle"!*

Answer (score 0):

> I have an abstract class base with private member variable base_var

```
class foo { 
public:
    virtual void a_pure_virtual_method() = 0;                           
    int get_var() { base_var; }
    virtual ~foo(){}
private:
    int base_var;
};
```

Note that a class is said to be abstract when it has at least one pure virtual (aka abstract) method. There is nothing that forbids an abstract class to have non-pure virtual or even non-virtual methods.

> I want to create a derived class, which also has base_var as a private member.

```
class derived : public foo {};
```

> To me, this seems like an obvious thing you would want to do.

Sure, no problem so far.

> The only time I will create a base-object is if it is actually a derived object, so obviously when I give ´base´ a private member variable, what I am really trying to do is give that variable to all of its derived objects.

Still fine.

> Why not?

You are confusing access rights that are display in the image you included with the mere presence of the members in the derived. The derived class has no access to members that are private in the base class. Period. This is just according to the definition of what is private.

> What would then even be the point of having private stuff in an abstract class? That class will never be instantiated, so all that private stuff is essentially useless?

It is not useless at all. Derived classes inherit all members, they just cannot access all of them. The private stuff is there you just cannot access it directly. Thats the whole point of encapsulation. Consider this example:

```
class bar : public foo {
    void test() {
        std::cout << base_var;  // error base_var is private in foo
        std::cout << get_var(); // fine
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because a class is abstract doesn't mean there cannot be code implemented in that class that might access that variable. When you declare an item in a class to be private, the compiler assumes you had a good reason and will not change the access just because it there is a pure virtual function in the class.

If you want your derived classes to have access to a base class member declare the member as protected.